# How to differentiate b/w the REST API calls made from UI client and REST Client

Tags: rest, api

I have a bunch of REST API exposed in my application. I need to differentiate between the calls made from UI client(user clicking a button or submitting the form) and the calls made from network. For example in mozilla browser user can open the network tab and call the API with different parameters(as long as user still signed in and within the same session).  Is there anyway we can check in API implementation whether this call is coming from UI client or just REST client? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could add HTTP headers in the client request.

Comment: Don't think this will help as the same headers will be passed when user sends the request through browser resend button

Comment: So? All you asked for was differentiating between a UI/Browser and REST client

Comment: Yes thats right

Answer (score 0):

HTTP clients can provide information about themselves over the **User-Agent** request header.

See [RFC-1945: HTTP - User Agent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#page-46)

Non-browser clients can set their own identifier/information as `User-Agent` request header when performing REST requests, allowing the server to serve custom-tailered content depending on the consuming user agent.

Comment: Couldn't any request be modified to do this though?

Comment: @RobertBain: yes, of course, any client can set or fake that header arbitrarily. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing

Comment: I checked User Agent header.. Again when i resend the request from browser it is copying all the headers that were passed from UI client.          User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0

Comment: I guess it's how important knowing where the request came from is. I suppose if you have a public REST API, you know who's who based on login data and they're already trusted enough to get access. I can't imagine there would be much of an attack vector irritating people by pretending to be a UI call, and indeed, how would they know what headers to add.

Comment: @RobertBain: Yes you are right all these calls are coming from a trusted user(authenticated and authorized as there is a active session, Yes with out a active session one can't do this). But in my case there some exception cases where we should restrict user from resending the request with changed parameters.

Comment: @SBB the problem I see is that the REST requests don't know anything about the previous requests. Perhaps you could assign users with roles. Have a network user and a UI user and only let them perform certain actions?

Comment: Even to do that i need to know whether the call is from REST or UI

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to differentiate. Once the user is authenticated they have a session and can call the services they're authorised to and pass in any parameters that are accepted by the resource.

If we assume no-one is deliberately faking it from the REST client, adding data in the UI request to say it's from the UI would work, but an evil REST client could send the same request.